# hibernate delete nested element manytomany

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm here for a probably trivial question...

I have an object like that:

```
public class MyObject {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  protected Long                   id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  protected List<MyObject>     parents;

}
```

Simple question: How can I simply delete an instance of MyObject and remove all its eventual references in "parents" list of others MyObject instances ?

For now, to remove them all (clear the table in fact), I do that in my dao manager :

```
@Override
public void removeAllMyObject() {
  // Remove all parents before deleting entity
  // that is the part I would skip
  for (MyObject myObject: getAllMyObject()) {
    myObject.getParents().clear();
  }

  // Remove all MyObject
  for (MyObject myObject : getAllMyObject()) {
    dao.remove(myObject);
  }
}
```

with dao.remove(T obj):

```
@Override
public void remove(T obj) {
  getSession().delete(obj);
  getSession().flush();
}
```

I don't know if the solution is in the cascadeType.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If this is your entire mapping you'd just remove all parents from the list (or delete the entity itself) since the child is the owner of the relation in that case. However, you asked for "remove it from all parents list" which indicates parents have a list of children as well, if so we need that mapping. Or do you want to remove a parent? If so then what should happen with the children?

Comment: The real question is : is there a way with session.delete(myObject), with myObject an instance of MyObject ? Knowing that myObject can be in some "parents" of other instance of MyObject.